# Is it possible to run hashtab.dll in standalone mode?

Tags: dll

This is my first post and I hope I am posting in the right section. I would like to know if it is possible to execute a dll file (here, hashtab.dll) as if it's a standalone application. Tried using dependency walker, but I have no idea of interpreting the results and the errors. Only if I can do that, I'll be able to use rundll.exe to execute the function. Any ideas on how to get this done?